# Sich bewusst sein/werden: with or without anticipatory pronoun?

Tags: word-usage

What would one do in this case? Can the anticipatory pronoun just be left out altogether, as in

> 1 - Ich bin mir bewusst, dass er morgen kommen wird

or do we need eg

> 2 - Ich bin mir dessen bewusst, dass er morgen kommen wird

(not sure "dessen" is the right one, but seems logical since a genitive is required there)

Comment: Yes, "dessen" is the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leave our the *dessen* if you change the sentence slightly:

> Mir ist bewusst, dass er morgen kommen wird.

(In fact, then you *need* to leave out the *dessen*, as you can not say *Mir ist dessen bewusst, ...*)

If you want to keep the form *Ich bin mir*, you need to say

> Ich bin mir dessen bewusst, dass ...

Comment: FWIW in spoken language that doesn't matter. I heard the first example sentence more than enough, and personally must say, I don't dislike it...

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - Ich bin mir bewusst, dass er morgen kommen wird

and also *Mir ist bewusst* is used like that. You can add *dessen* in the first case, but it's totally normal to do without.

You must use **dessen** if you substitute something that has been said (or written) before and you are referring to it

> 3 - A: Er wird schon morgen kommen. B: Ich bin mir **dessen** bewusst. (***Das*** ist mir bewusst.)